# mod_rewrite causing glob() thumb images to no longer display?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page with a bunch of products on it. Using the following link I can select one item, based on id, and look at the specifications/pictures related to just that item

```
http://www.example.com/products/index.php?id=20
```

This brings up the information for the product with id 20. Works fine, all images/specifications display and nothing is broken.

But whenever I try to implement any sort of RewriteRule SOME (I'll explain) of my thumbs stop displaying.

Here is an example rewrite rule I am trying. I am keeping it simple purely for trying to troubleshoot this issue:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/$ /products/index.php?id=$1&model=$2 [L]
```

Then in /products/index.php my product links look like this:

```
<a href="/products/$product-id/$product-model-name/">Product Name</a>
```

This works great and gives me url such as:

```
www.example.com/20/product-model-name/
```

And the information for the selected product is displaying via the script below (I am sanitizing etc, this is shortened for testing):

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['model'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $m = $_GET['model'];
  $get_product_stats = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT products.*, company.company_name FROM products INNER JOIN company ON products.company_id=company.id WHERE products.id='$id' AND products.model='$m'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_product_stats);
    if (!$row) {
        echo 'Error';
        exit();
    }
$company_name = $row['company_name'];
$product_model = $row['model'];
$product_model_abbr = $row['product_model_abbr'];
if ($row['product_model_version'] == NULL) { $image_directory_name = "/products/$company_name/$product_model_abbr/"; } else $image_directory_name = "/products/$company_name/$product_model_abbr (" . $row['product_model_version'] . ")/";

$top = "$image_directory_name" . "top.jpg";
echo "<div><img src='$top'></div>"; // THIS DISPLAYS FINE.

// echo some more item specifications here
// and lastly:

echo '<div>';
  $images = glob($image_directory_name."*_thumb*");
    if (!$images) {
        echo '<p>Currently no images for this product.</p>'; // I get this error
    }
else {
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $full = str_replace('thumb','full',$image);
        echo '<a href="'.$full.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

The images (the 'top.jpg', thumbs and full size images) for each product are stored directly in:

```
/products/company name/model name/
```

So in the code above, before I implement rewrite, the top thumb shows up, and the bottom set of thumbs show up. After implementing rewrite, the top thumb shows up, and the bottom ones do not. Yet they are all in the same directory, using the same variable to reach them.

I am baffled. Someone please save me, I've been grinding my brain against this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/$ /products/index.php?id=$1&model=$2 [L]`

Comment: Thank you so much for replying - the bottom thumbs still do not appear though. It just doesn't make any sense to me, since the top.jpg thumb works... and the glob() works before implenting rewriting.